# Dynamically adding JQUERY tabs, getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-ui

I'm pretty sure there's an error in one of my strings, but I can't find it. The goal of this code is to dynamically add the Facebook comments plugin to tabs depending on what episode of a show I work for you are listening to.

```
    $('body').attr('id', 'tabs');
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            $('#tabs').ready(function(){discussion(222); });

                    function discussion(episodeNumber){
        var tabNum =$('#tabs').size('a') + 1;
        console.log(tabNum);
    $('#tabs').append('<div id=\"#tabs-'+tabNum+'\">'+episodeNumber+'</a></li>');
        $('#tabs-'+tabNum).ready(function(episodeNumber,tabNum){$('#tabs-'+tabNum).append('<p><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1\"></script><fb:comments href=\"http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com%2Fepisodes%2Ffoo_foo_foo-'+episodeNumber+'.php&amp;h=BAQCj6iHg\" num_posts=\"10\" width=\"50\"></fb:comments></p>');
        });
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the syntax errors, but your HTML is incorrect as well. You are appending an open div tag with a closing a and li tag!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to start those tags. Thanks! I'll post again if this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/, you can add a tab this way:

`$('#tabs').tabs('add',null,'tab label', indexId);`

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-add for more info.